# how to configure log4j to log sql statements from mybatis

Tags: java, groovy, log4j, mybatis

I am using MyBatis3 I need a way to log all my select, insert, update statements to my log4j log file.

Here is my log4j file. Please help

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=test.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=2MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way, putting in so others can benefit too

In order to log sql statements download Simple Logging Facade for Java ([download slf4j here](http://www.slf4j.org/download.html))

Added the following to my classpath, apart from regular mybatis, odbc and oracle jars

1. log4j-xxxx.jar
2. log4j-over-slf4j-xxxx.jar
3. log4j-rolling-appender.jar
4. slf4j-api-xxxx.jar
5. slf-log4j12-xxxx.jar

**Note**: xxxx is appropriate version here

and append the following lines in my log4j (see my question)

```
# logger debug
log4j.logger.test.Log4jTestMyBatis=DEBUG, convert
log4j.appender.convert = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.convert.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.convert.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{HH:mm:ss}] %-5p %c{3} %x - %m%n
# end logger debug

# mybatis loggers #
log4j.logger.com.ibatis=DEBUG, convert
log4j.logger.com.ibatis.common.jdbc.SimpleDataSource=DEBUG, convert
log4j.logger.com.ibatis.common.jdbc.ScriptRunner=DEBUG, convert
log4j.logger.com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapClientDelegate=DEBUG, convert
```

Here is a Groovy class example that I used for testing

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSession;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;

import com.abc.db.ConfigInfo;
import com.abc.db.ConfigInfoExample;
import com.abc.db.client.ConfigInfoMapper;
import com.abc.db.init.DatabaseConnectivity;



class Log4jTestMyBatis {

    static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jTestMyBatis.class)

    static main(args) {
        PropertyConfigurator.configure(Log4jTestMyBatis.class.getResource("log4j.properties"));

        DatabaseConnectivity.init()
        SqlSession newABCSession = DatabaseConnectivity.getNewABCSessionFactory().openSession()

        ConfigInfoMapper mapper = newABCSession.getMapper(ConfigInfoMapper.class)
        ConfigInfoExample qExample = new ConfigInfoExample()
        qExample.createCriteria().andProjectIdEqualTo("0-12170")
        List<ConfigInfo> ctlist = mapper.selectByExample(qExample)

        logger.debug(ctlist.get(0).getCfgName())

        newABCSession.close()
        logger.debug("debug")

    }   

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can see the Log4J configuration info [here](http://www.mybatis.org/core/logging.html). In short - you need to set Log4J loglevel to DEBUG or TRACE on your mapper or mapper package or specific mapper method. E.g. `log4j.logger.org.mybatis.example.BlogMapper.selectBlog=TRACE`. TRACE will print SQL, params and resultsets, and DEBUG will print SQL and params only.